# Unicode error PyPdf

Tags: python, python-requests, pypdf

I try to download several pdfs using the `requests` library and merge them together using pypdf. In general, this is working fine but for some pdfs I just get an error.

MWE.py

```
import requests
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
from StringIO import StringIO


input = PdfFileReader(StringIO(response.content))
input.decrypt("")
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(input.getPage(0))

outputStream = file("document-output.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

session.close()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mwe.py", line 21, in <module>
    input.decrypt("")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 894, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt(password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 904, in _decrypt
    user_password, key = self._authenticateUserPassword(password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 945, in _authenticateUserPassword
    encrypt.get("/EncryptMetadata", BooleanObject(False)).getObject())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 1818, in _alg35
    key = _alg32(password, rev, keylen, owner_entry, p_entry, id1_entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyPdf/pdf.py", line 1729, in _alg32
    m.update(id1_entry)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

For the trace I read the input from a file but I don't think that it matters in this case.

I found some related questions to this issue but I am unable to solve my specific problem.

Comment: Were you going to share the rest of the traceback?

Comment: The error occures in the decrypt method doesn't it? Actually the pdf is not encrypted but I found this workaround with the empty password. Otherwise it fails with `Exception: file has not been decrypted` inside the addPage method.

Comment: Why are you using `file`? You should really use `open`

Comment: Because I am touching Python only once in a while and don't know all the do's and dont's. It was in the documentation of pyPdf like that and therefore I used it. I changed it in my code because you seem to have good reasons why open should be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that this seems to be a bug inside pyPdf (1.13)
https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/51

Using PyPDF2 (1.26.0) instead works as expected so far.